# javascript function equivalent for vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I'm new in here so I would appreciate some guidance in writing a Google Script function that sets a value in column B of sheet 1, looking up a value in column A of sheet 1 into sheet 2 column A to C.

To be very specific - Sheet 1 contains

```
  A      B
names  emails
```

Sheet 2 contains

```
  A      B       C
date   names   emails
```

I want to insert in column B from Sheet 1 the email address from Sheet 2, with the name as unique identifier.

Comment: Google Sheets does support VLOOKUP - what's the reason you can't use that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,3);
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,3).getValues()[0];
  var hi={nA:[]};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){hi[h]=i;});
  var v=rg.getValues();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    var r1=r[hi['names']];
    var r2=r[hi['emails']];
    if(!hi.hasOwnProperty(r[hi['names']])) {
      hi[r[hi['names']]]=[];
      hi[r[hi['names']]].push(r[hi['emails']]);
      hi.nA.push(r[hi['names']]);
    }else{
      if(hi[r[hi['names']]].indexOf(r[hi['emails']])==-1) {
        hi[r[hi['names']]].push(r[hi['emails']]);
      }
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(1,5,sh.getLastRow(),2).clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1,5,1,2).setValues([['names','emails']]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  var row=2;
  var col=5;
  hi.nA.forEach(function(n,i){
    hi[n].forEach(function(e,j){
      if(!j) {
        sh.getRange(row++,col,1,2).setValues([[n,e]]);
      }else{
        sh.getRange(row++,col,1,2).setValues([['',e]]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

animation of sheets:

[image]

Answer to JSON question:

```
function jsonplay() {
  var json=JSON.parse('{"cartItems":{"1c383cd30b7c298ab50293adfecb7b18":{"id":"35","image":"images\/products\/banner\/2019-11-02-10-59-29.jpeg","name":"Voltas 1.2 Ton 3 Star Split Inverter AC - White","model":"153V DZV (R32)","qty":12,"price":27999,"online_charge":"50","cod":"50","free_delivery":"no","rowid":"1c383cd30b7c298ab50293adfecb7b18","subtotal":335988},"3295c76acbf4caaed33c36b1b5fc2cb1":{"id":"66","image":"images\/products\/banner\/2019-11-22-14-53-27.jpg","name":"Alarm Clock With LED","model":"AA-3007","qty":2,"price":228,"online_charge":"0","cod":"0","free_delivery":"no","rowid":"3295c76acbf4caaed33c36b1b5fc2cb1","subtotal":456}}}');
  var keys=Object.keys(json.cartItems);
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black}</style><table><tr><th>id</th><th>image</th><th>name</th><th>model</th><th>qty</th><th>Price</th><th>online_charge</th><th>cod</th><th>free_delivery</th><th>rowid</th><th>subtotal</th></tr>';
  Logger.log(keys);
  for(key in json.cartItems) {
    var obj=json.cartItems[key];
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',obj.id,obj.image,obj.name,obj.model,obj.qty,obj.price,obj.online_charge,obj.cod,obj.free_delivery,obj.rowid,obj.subtotal);
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Data');
}
```